# Criando archive.php no wordpress usando campo personalizado

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Estou tentando criar uma página de agenda no WordPress onde o usuário seleciona o mês por um `select`:

```
<select>
     <option>Janeiro 2015</option>
     <option>Dezembro 2014</option>
     <option>Novembro 2014</option>
     <option>Outubro 2014</option>
     <option>Setembro 2014</option>
</select>
```

Em seguida os posts são carregados via Ajax. Eu criei um formulário do tipo `POST` chamado `agenda` e um campo personalizado chamado `agenda_data`.

Eu preciso de ajuda em dois itens, o restante acho que consigo desenrolar sozinho.

1. No `select` aparecem os últimos 12 meses, a função do WordPress `wp_get_archives` faz isso. Porém ela retorna baseado nas datas de publicação e eu gostaria que fosse baseado na data do campo personalizado.
2. Um `archive.php` que exiba os posts também baseado na data do campo personalizado e não pela data de publicação do post.

Não achei nada ainda na internet que pudesse me ajudar.

Comment: não entendi a parte `baseado na data do campo personalizado.` Que campo é este? Como você o personaliza?

Comment: Mostra o form completo.

Comment: Um campo personalizado, onde você informa a data do evento, entendeu ?

Comment: Sergio, poderia colocar o código que você está usando? O valor do campo personalizado está sendo gravado como data ou com outro formato? Poderia colocar o código do que cria o campo personalizado tb?

Comment: Opa Ricardo, tudo bem ? agora estou usando a data mesmo nativa do Wordpress. Eu não sabia mas é possível exibir uma postagem mesmo ela estando agendada para uma data futura, usando 'post_status' => 'future'. Agora só estou com problemas no carregamento por ajax mesmo.

Comment: @SérgioMachado, você conseguiu resolver o problema, usando o `wp_get_archives()`? E como você está fazendo o carregamento AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que não tem muito jeito, os filtros disponíveis na função [`wp_get_archives`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) não são suficientes para fazer essa filtragem. A solução é copiar a função para uma `meu_get_archives($args)` e adaptar às suas necessidades: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1354

Quanto à página `archive.php`, em vez do tradicional `<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>`, tem que fazer um [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) personalizado, usando o parâmetros [Order & Orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters):

```
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby' => 'meta_val_num'
```

Ou então poderia usar o filtro [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), que é o recomendado para filtrar a query principal e deixar a o template `archive.php` do jeito que é.

<sup>Referências:</sup>
 <sup>- [Order Custom Post Type Archive by multiple values in functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/88496/12615)</sup>
 <sup>- [Archive Listings Filtered by Date Values in a Custom Field/Post Meta?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5800/12615) (aqui, a resposta do Mike Schinkel é uma *master class*)</sup>